# External Hard Drive with no WMI info

Tags: windows, windows-8, external-hard-drive, wmi

Had some software crash for a user because it expected TotalSectors from WMI to be present for all `Win32_DiskDrive`'s. The powershell output for it is below.

I asked the user if there was something wrong with the device and he responded "I use it everywhere just fine, but i know sometimes windows asks to 'fix' something in there, and always click 'No'."

I'm curious what might be wrong with it so I can advise other users who might have a similar issue before a patch can be released. Also, how I might be able to force a device to present like this for testing purposes.

```
PSComputerName              : censored-PC
ConfigManagerErrorCode      : 0
LastErrorCode               :
NeedsCleaning               :
Status                      : OK
DeviceID                    : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
StatusInfo                  :
Partitions                  : 0
BytesPerSector              :
ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False
DefaultBlockSize            :
Index                       : 1
InstallDate                 :
InterfaceType               : USB
MaxBlockSize                :
MaxMediaSize                :
MinBlockSize                :
NumberOfMediaSupported      :
SectorsPerTrack             :
Size                        :
TotalCylinders              :
TotalHeads                  :
TotalSectors                :
TotalTracks                 :
TracksPerCylinder           :
__GENUS                     : 2
__CLASS                     : Win32_DiskDrive
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_DiskDrive
__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                   : Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE1"
__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 51
__DERIVATION                : {CIM_DiskDrive, CIM_MediaAccessDevice, CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement...}
__SERVER                    : censored-PC
__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2
__PATH                      : \\censored-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE1"
Availability                :
Capabilities                :
CapabilityDescriptions      :
Caption                     : Generic- Multi-Card USB Device
CompressionMethod           :
CreationClassName           : Win32_DiskDrive
Description                 : Unidad de disco
ErrorCleared                :
ErrorDescription            :
ErrorMethodology            :
FirmwareRevision            : 1.00
Manufacturer                : (Unidades de disco estándar)
MediaLoaded                 : True
MediaType                   :
Model                       : Generic- Multi-Card USB Device
Name                        : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
PNPDeviceID                 : USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_GENERIC-&PROD_MULTI-CARD&REV_1.00\20090516388200000&0
PowerManagementCapabilities :
PowerManagementSupported    :
SCSIBus                     : 0
SCSILogicalUnit             : 0
SCSIPort                    : 0
SCSITargetId                : 0
SerialNumber                : 20090516388200000
Signature                   : 0
SystemCreationClassName     : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName                  : censored-PC
Scope                       : System.Management.ManagementScope
Path                        : \\censored-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE1"
Options                     : System.Management.ObjectGetOptions
ClassPath                   : \\censored-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive
Properties                  : {Availability, BytesPerSector, Capabilities, CapabilityDescriptions...}
SystemProperties            : {__GENUS, __CLASS, __SUPERCLASS, __DYNASTY...}
Qualifiers                  : {dynamic, Locale, provider, UUID}
Site                        :
Container                   :
```

Comment: for me it works. Maybe the SATA to USB controller doesn't support those information.

Comment: What information is reported is entirely up to the firmware of the controller.  Information about the storage device would be helpful.

Comment: All I have at the moment is that its a WD device.